# how to implement oauth2.0 client(password grant type) without forcing users to login?

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, oauth2client

I'm trying to develop OAuth2.0 client application(Resource Owner Password Credentials Authorization Grant)with Spring-Boot1.5.9(restful service)  but unlike every sample on the Internet, I don't want to have a Login page for consumers to log in and submit credentials to me.

I just want consumers to call my API to obtain secured resources which are on different servers.
The client only has to call my restful service without making anyone log in first and then my API has to call an oauth2.0 secured restful service. I have been registered my profile on remote authorization server and received my user/pass credentials to call those restful services.

I have tested my credentials with POSTMAN and successfully called those secured APIs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *I don't want to have a Login page for consumers to log in and submit credentials to me.* Without username and password you can't use Resource Owner Password grant type. You need to send the credentials to your client.

Comment: *I have been registered my profile on remote authorization server and received my user/pass credentials to call those restful services.* It sound like you want to use Client Credentials grant type.